# Json Module Cannot Be Installed with Pip

Tags: python, json, pip, version, spyder

I am trying to install `json` using `pip` but it is showing an error.

```
pip install json
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement json (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for json
Note: you may need to restart the kernel to use updated packages.
```

I am using `pip` version 21.1.1

Answer (score 2):

The [`json`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html) module is built into python, so there is no need to install it. Python has many built in modules, full list here: https://docs.python.org/3/py-modindex.html.